# Unable to connect to SQL database via Excel VBA

Tags: sql-server, vba

I am unable to connect to my database using VBA:

```
Sub testSub()
    Dim cn As Object
    Dim cnStr As String
    cnStr = "DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=myServerName;Database=myDbName;Trusted_Connection=Yes"
    Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    With cn
        .ConnectionString = cnStr
        .ConnectionTimeout = 10
        .Open
        If .State = 1 Then
            'rest of code
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

the code fails on the .Open line with the error message:

[image]

No problems connecting to this database via SSMS. Also, no problems connecting to some other databases using the above VBA. Any idea why it's not allowing me to connect via Excel/VBA and how to fix this, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the new [Microsoft OLE DB Driver for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/oledb/oledb-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) or even the new [Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15).

See [Using ADO with OLE DB Driver for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/oledb/applications/using-ado-with-oledb-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) for guidance on updating VB, VBA, and ASP.OLD apps to use the new driver.